# Call Class From Python Script

Tags: python

How would you call the below MLStripper class from another Python script?

**Main Python Script:**

```
    import ConfigParser
    import os
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

    c = imaplib_connect.open_connection()
    try:
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.read([os.path.expanduser('~/reader.config')])
        test = MLStripper.strip_tags("<br>testing</br>")
        print test
```

**Class I Want to Call:**

```
 class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
            def __init__(self):
                 self.reset()
                 self.fed = []
            def handle_data(self, d):
                 self.fed.append(d)
            def get_data(self):
                 return ''.join(self.fed)

            def strip_tags(html):
                 s = MLStripper()
                 s.feed(html)
                 return s.get_data()
```

Comment: Start by working through [a Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). "Calling a class" isn't really a thing to begin with.

Comment: If you want to call a class, you should use the `__call__` magic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the class needs to be instatiated first:

```
import ConfigParser
import os
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

c = imaplib_connect.open_connection()
try:
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read([os.path.expanduser('~/reader.config')])
    ML = MLStripper()
    test = ML.strip_tags("<br>testing</br>")
    print test
```

Comment: you need to import `MLStripper`

Comment: ie, if `class MLStripper` is in a file called mlstripper.py, at the top of your file you should say `from mlstripper import MLStripper`

Comment: I have everything in the same file for now.  I moved it to the top as the class needed to be defined first before instantiating it.  I get test = ML.strip_tags("<br>testing</br>")
TypeError: strip_tags() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given), but I don't see why strip_tags is saying I'm passing 2 arguments, any ideas?

Comment: a separate problem, you need to add a `self` to the function, ie, `def strip_tags(self, html):`